# Excel 2007 VBA Autofiltr: Select Case IsEmpty vs Copying

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling with my macro.

GOAL & MAIN IDEA:
It opens different xls files, based on Autofilter it checks 10th column to choose the rows with four "last-friday-days" (so if we have 18/02 it returns 13/02, 06/02, 30/01, 23/01.)

PROBLEM:
Problem is only when in my file there are no dates like aboves.Even though the file should be closed automatically it try to copying empty range!! I use Select Case (code below)

[image: empty selection but it is still copying]

CODE:

```
 Rows("4:4").Select '*Autofilter - this part is ok*
 Selection.AutoFilter *' four last-Fridays from the Column - ok*
 ActiveSheet.Range("J5", Range("J5").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array( _
    LastFridayDate, Friday2weeksagoDate, Friday3weeksagoDate, Friday4weeksagoDate), Operator:= _
       xlFilterValues

Range("A4").Offset(1, 0).Activate
  Select Case IsEmpty(ActiveCell) ' *MISTAKE!!* 
    Case True MISTAKE!! *no data in file, file should be closed!*
        Workbooks("prima UKACZEE.xls").Close SaveChanges:=False
    Case Else ' *this part always works*
        Range("A5", Range("A5").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks("Makro XXX Claim Hours v.01.xls").Sheets("TRN Claim Report - Labour").Activate
        Range("A5").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False *' closing file - ok*
    Workbooks("prima UKACZEE.xls").Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Select
```

If you could help. Appreciate

Comment: The screenshot in your question doesn't do a lot (if anything) to help explain your problem. Have you tried stepping through the code manually (add a breakpoint before the problematic code and then execute it line-by-line by pressing F8)? It sounds like `IsEmpty(ActiveCell)` is always evaluating to False and thus your `Case True` is never being executed. Stepping through the code should be able to confirm or deny this.

Comment: As you said: IsEmpty(ActiveCell) is always evaluating to False and thus  Case True is never executed. TO be honest I do not really know how to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that AutoFilter doesn't make rows non-existent, it simply hides them. Regardless of whether a filter has been applied `Range("A4").Offset(1,0)` will always refer to cell A5 so if there's a value in A5 then `IsEmpty(ActiveCell)` will always return false.

To solve this problem you're going to have to use the [SpecialCells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) method of the Range object. The below code will activate the 1st visible cell in column A that's below cell A4, in your case the first row of results after filtering.

```
Range("A5:A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Activate
```

Comment: Hi Aiken, that is exactly what I need, that is the idea. So you mean instead Range("A4").Offset(1,0) in my code above i should put just: 
Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(5, 1).Activate ? And that is the only change, yep? Because that is what I did and it still reads the whole code as before... but at least there is no error messages as for now.

Comment: @user3506071 I did a little testing and the edited line of code in my answer should work.